# How would I be able to edit data within the textboxes which will then update the current database for a user's profile?

Tags: database, vb.net

I have managed to display the specific record from the database however if my user feels the need to edit the current information in his/her profile which will then update to the database once the user presses the 'Save Changes' button, how would I go about coding this?

Current Code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class MyProfile
Dim con As OleDbConnection
Private Sub MyProfile_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con = New OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ParkwoodValeHarriers\ParkwoodValeHarriers\PVH.accdb")
    con.Open()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dbCursor As Integer = 0
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ParkwoodValeHarriers\ParkwoodValeHarriers\PVH.accdb"
    da.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select [Gender], [Forename], [Surname], [Date_of_Birth], [Height], [Weight], [Address], [City], [Country], [Email_Address], [Telephone_Number], [Username] From T_LoginAndProfile Where Username  = '" & txtUsername1.Text & "'", con)
    da.SelectCommand.Connection = conn

    da.Fill(ds)

    Me.txtGender.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(dbCursor).Item("Gender").ToString()
    Me.txtForename.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(dbCursor).Item("Forename").ToString()
    Me.txtSurname.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(dbCursor).Item("Surname").ToString()
    Me.txtDateOfBirth.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(dbCursor).Item("Date_Of_Birth").ToString()
    Me.txtHeight.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(dbCursor).Item("Height").ToString()
    Me.txtWeight.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(dbCursor).Item("Weight").ToString()
    Me.txtAddress.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(dbCursor).Item("Address").ToString()
    Me.txtCity.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(dbCursor).Item("City").ToString()
    Me.txtCountry.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(dbCursor).Item("Country").ToString()
    Me.txtEmailAddress.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(dbCursor).Item("Email_Address").ToString()
    Me.txtTelephoneNumber.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(dbCursor).Item("Telephone_Number").ToString()
    Me.txtUsername1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(dbCursor).Item("Username").ToString()
    conn.Close()


End Sub
```

Comment: You would have to add a button to your form, read up on the Click event of the button. When you handle that click event, you can get the value of your textbox with the .Text property like you did for loading. After that you update your database.

Comment: Sorry if I sound stupid to you :/ but could you provide me an example of a piece of code for one of the lines such as Address?

Comment: What do you mean? Your question is very broad...

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was could you give me an example of code that would proceed to allow the editing button to work?

Comment: [Data Access QuickStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648171.aspx)

Comment: @AlexDada simply retrieve the values of your textboxes and write an Update query for your OleDb.OleDbCommand.